# Can someone explain this trend of Control Voltage Vs Output Freq? Circuit configured:- 555 IC as a VCO

Tags: analog, 555, digital-communications, frequency-response, vco

So, in my Master's, while going through a lab for analog electronics, we were given this seemingly pointless task of plotting Control Voltage vs Output Freq when a 555 IC is configured as a VCO.
The experiment was done, and the following results were obtained. I've been breaking my head to understand WHY the dip actually occurs in this trend. WHY exactly is the output frequency peaking at a point before diving again?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The key to understanding the 555 is to plot the signals for THR, TRIG, CV, and CV/2 on the same graph, and think about what the internal SR flipflops are doing.  When things are a little hard to understand is the condition where S and R are asserted at the same time.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that the two voltage comparators in the 555 do not really have rail-to-rail capable inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The key to understanding this is that you first need to understand how this circuit works without the control voltage input connected.

There are two voltage levels (1/3Vcc and 2/3Vcc) that limit the charging/discharging of the connected capacitor which leads to an oscillation of the capacitor voltage between these two voltage levels.

The control input voltage kind of stretches or squeezes these levels. So a higher voltage at the control input stretches the capacitor oscillation amplitude, so the output frequency decreases. That‘s what you see in your measurements. When the control voltage is 0V, the oscillation does not work (which is 0Hz).

So it is pure logical reasoning that there must be a frequency peak somewhere between 0V and the decreasing frequency curve you measured.